# Serverless - Use pre-generated api gateway url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

Am I able to define a pre-generated api gateway url for my serverless application?

Currently there are two applications already made that has their own that was generated with cloud formation. The new application is using the serverless framework.

The client asked that I reuse the one that was generated for the other two applications on mine to extend the amount of endpoints over having its own url.

It’s not a custom url that uses a cname just a straight generated api gateway one they would like me to piggy back off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do that with AWS-provided URLs. The only way to join several APIs under a single URL domain is to use **custom domains**. Then you can hook up multiple APIs to one domain, e.g. `api.mydomain.org`, `api2.mydomain.org`.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try to convince them to use a cname instead.